# Include Rspec examples with variable

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a few sets of rspecs that all include some shared examples.  I would like those shared examples to then include other shared examples, if the original spec had some variable set.  Basically this is what I'm trying to do.

Example:

File: `spec/test_spec.rb`

```
describe 'some thing' do
  let(:some_feature) { true }

  describe 'some tests' do
    include_examples "shared_tests" 
  end
end
```

File `spec/shared/shared_tests.rb`

```
shared_examples_for "shared_tests" do
  include_examples "feature_specific_tests" if some_feature
end
```

As expected, this is throwing an error like this:

```
undefined local variable or method `some_feature`
```

Is there a way to do this?  I thought perhaps I could define `@some_feature` in a `before(:all)` block and then use `if @some_feature` in the `shared_examples`, but that is always `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting the answer to make it a little clearer:

You had this:

File: spec/test_spec.rb

```
describe 'some thing' do
  let(:some_feature) { true }

  describe 'some tests' do
    include_examples "shared_tests" 
  end
end
```

File spec/shared/shared_tests.rb

```
shared_examples_for "shared_tests" do
  include_examples "feature_specific_tests" if some_feature
end
```

Change it to:

File: spec/test_spec.rb

```
describe 'some thing' do

  describe 'some tests' do
    include_examples "shared_tests" do
      let(:some_feature) { true }
    end
  end
end
```

File spec/shared/shared_tests.rb

```
shared_examples "shared_tests" do
  if some_feature
    it_should_behave_like "feature_specific_tests"
  end

  # rest of your tests for shared example group
  # 'a logged in registered user goes here
end
```

And it'll all work nicely :-)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  The question is more like how to only use `it_should_behave_like "some tests" if some_feature` as the variable is outside of its scope

Comment: right - see the bottom code block - just shift your let(:some_feature) line down from where you had it into a block you feed your first shared examples call... compare the block I put at the bottom to your original block up top.  You're just effectively passing a truthy value through to the shared example set, in a block, which will then be available within the second group...

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: I've laid it out like you described, but I still get an `undefined method` error in the shared_examples...  Somehow I'm not grasping this.

Comment: Hmm... this is how I've got it done in several test suites... let me go over the code again and make sure I've not done anything stupid.

Comment: Have you checked out the rspec docs link WARNING: Files containing... section - and ensured you're loading and requiring in the right order?  If your shared examples file loads before your test_spec file for any reason you'll get that error.  They have some explanation of how to do that on that link I posted...

Comment: Ahh, I'm willing to bet that is probably my problem.  I'll check into that and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: NP - update when you know what's going on - I'm intrigued to track this down as I have been using shared_contexts and shared_examples a bit recently and find them a fantastic tool, if a bit fiddly.

Comment: It is most definitely the order the files are being required.  Any time I require the file with the shared examples, it throws the undefined method error.  Of course, if I don't require it anywhere, it obviously can't find the shared examples...